# Как сохранить [,] массив в файл?

Tags: c#

Как сохранить двумерный массив (объявляю как `[,]`) в `.txt` файл как он есть? В матрице или бинарном видe — точно не знаю пока, как правильно.

Comment: а зачем вам нужен массив в txt файле?

Comment: смотреть что туда попадает, в случае проблем. До другого способа пока не додумался.

Comment: а что может быть в вашем массиве, какого типа там бывают элементы?

Comment: @mymedia типа string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не слишком эффективно, зато удобно, что в одну строку

```
File.WriteAllText("array.txt", string.Concat(array.Cast<string>().Select((s, i) => s + ((i+1) % array.GetLength(1) == 0 ? "\n" : " "))));
```

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/eyPvJM

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string[,] array = { { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }, { "q", "w", "e" } };

    //System.IO.File.WriteAllText("array.txt",
    Console.Write(
      string.Concat(array.Cast<string>().Select(
        (s, i) => s + ((i+1) % array.GetLength(1) == 0 ? "\n" : " ")
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Здорово, без танцев смог прикрутить, но есть потери(

Comment: @Vipz, выбери подходящие разделители вместо `" "` и `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

Подключаете к проекту nuget-пакет Json.Net.

Пишете:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr));
```

`arr` - ваш массив.

Не забудьте указать пространства имён:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Тащить целую библиотеку ради отладочного вывода? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть класс [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) из стандартной поставки

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string[,] array =
    {
        { "а", "б", "в"},
        { "г", "д", "е"}
    };

    string fileName = @"D:\array.txt";

    WriteToFile(array, fileName);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void WriteToFile(string[,] array, string fileName)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < array.GetLength(1); column++)
        {
            output.Append($"{array[row, column]}|");

        }
        output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, output.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"<--Ошибка записи в файл: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант для любителей Linq, должен быть более эффективен, чем в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736936/218063) за счет отсутствия сложения строк, но более трешовый:

```
string[,] array = { { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }, { "q", "w", "e" } };

Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("\n",
                Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
                          .Select(y => string.Join(" ",
                                                   Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1))
                                                             .Select(x => array[y, x]))))
);
```

Идея заключается в том, что с помощью генераторов `Enumerable.Range` мы получаем все пары индексов массива, а потом по ним собираем строки с помощью `string.Join`.

Никогда так не пишите!